# How to add Text Decoration to a List View row?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

My listview itemssource is an object called Person and it displays the Person.Name. I want to apply a text decoration for a specific row:

```
strikeThrough = new TextDecoration(TextDecorationLocation.Strikethrough, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), 0, TextDecorationUnit.FontRecommended, TextDecorationUnit.FontRecommended);
```

I want to cross out the whole row depending the Person.Name.

How can I apply this decoration to selected items in the listview?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a custom ItemTemplate to your ListView, and then create a binding to some property of your Person object.  That property can return the TextDecoration depending on the person's name.  Here's how:

**Person.cs:**

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PersonFullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }

    public TextDecorationCollection PersonTextDecorations
    {
        get
        {
            if (FirstName == "George")
            {
                return new TextDecorationCollection() 
                    { 
                        new TextDecoration
                            (
                            TextDecorationLocation.Strikethrough,
                            new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1), 
                            0, 
                            TextDecorationUnit.Pixel, 
                            TextDecorationUnit.Pixel
                            ) 
                    };
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Barack", LastName = "Obama" });
        persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "George", LastName = "Bush" });
        persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Clinton" });
        persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Ronald", LastName = "Reagan" });
        this.myListView.ItemsSource = persons;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
    <ListView x:Name="myListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonFullName}" TextDecorations="{Binding PersonTextDecorations}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Probably what OP needs, but `TextDecorationCollection` in (view)model feels a bit wrong. Perhaps it is better to remove GUI-dependent property and use instead value converter in binding to the whole object or to some special flag in it. `TemplateSelector` can also be used.